# Django JsonField Array data query

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a jsonfield in Postgres db and data like below:

```
income_info = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "A",
    "min_income": 22000
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "B",
    "min_income": 40000
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "C",
    "min_income": 22000
  }
]
```

Now want to use gte and lte over the django orm queryset. Already tried

```
Employee.objects.filter(income_info__min_income__lte = 4000000)
```

but did not work at all.

**models.py:**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    income_info = JSONField(default=list)
    others = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Comment: can you please share your models?

Comment: please check updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield) for querying JsonFields:

> If the key is an integer, it will be interpreted as an index lookup in an array

As your json data is list of json datas, you need a query like this:

```py
Employee.objects.filter(income_info__0__min_income__lte=4000000)
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to do that check only for the object with id 3? Considering I don't know its  position in the array?

Comment: Im not sure if you can do that. Maybe you can add an identifier field in your json schema and have a separate filter for that in your query?